# VisualVM on Heroku (with Docker)

Tags: java, scala, docker, heroku, visualvm

I have a Dockerized Scala Play app that I deploy to Heroku through their container registry. There seems to be a small memory leak in it. I'd like to troubleshoot this by using VisualVM but I am not able to connect VisualVM to the app in Heroku.

I have gone through these steps:

- I enabled the feature `runtime-heroku-exec`
- I installed the `heroku-cli-java`

When I run `heroku java:visualvm` against my app, I get the following response:

```
Establishing credentials... error
 ▸    Could not connect to dyno!
 ▸    Check if the dyno is running with 'heroku ps'
```

P.S. I suspect a memory leak, because Heroku reports, "R14 - Memory quota exceeded."

Any idea on how to enable VisualVM in a dockerized Heroku app?

Comment: I suspect the agents in the dyno aren't running. Do you see any `[heroku-exec]` errors when running `heroku logs`? Can you post those here? Also make sure your image has bash, curl, python, and openssh.

Comment: @codefinger No `[heroku-exec]` errors. Only `heroku[router]`, `heroku[web.1]` and `app[web.1]` logging entries (no errors). I am using the heroku:16 base image so I was told that bash, curl, python and openssh would be included (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#enabling-docker-support)

Comment: Do you see a `/app/.profile.d/heroku-exec.sh` file in your app with `heroku run`?

Comment: I ran `heroku run bash`and found no such file. I didn't even have an `/app/` folder

Comment: run `ls /app/.profile.d/`

Comment: I just get `cannot access '/app/.profile.d/': No such file or directory`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652928/shell-into-a-docker-container-running-on-a-heroku-dyno-how