# Shell into a Docker container running on a Heroku dyno. How?

Tags: docker, heroku

Given a dyno in which a container is running, what's the Heroku equivalent of `docker exec -it blarg /bin/bash`? That is, how can one open a shell into the already-running container?

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM heroku/heroku:16
CMD while true; do sleep 1; done
```

Example run:

```
$ heroku container:push my_app
<wait a minute>
$ heroku ps
=== my_app (Free): /bin/sh -c while\ true\;\ do\ sleep\ 1\;\ done (1) 
my_app.1: up 2017/10/09 12:13:07 -0600 (~ 4m ago)
```

So far so good.

But now...

```
$ heroku ps:exec --dyno=my_app.1
Establishing credentials... error
 ▸    Could not connect to dyno!
 ▸    Check if the dyno is running with `heroku ps'
```

For good measure I check `heroku ps` at this point and it shows that the dyno is still running.

Yes, I've done all the things Heroku suggests [to enable Docker support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#enabling-docker-support). Per the documentation, I have tried using a base image of my choice while ensuring that `bash`, `curl`, `openssh`, and `python` are present. I have also tried using the Heroku-16 base image, as shown in the above example.

(The linked documentation also references steps required for Private Spaces. Since I'm not using Private Spaces I have not applied those steps.)

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT CIRCA 2022** This was the accepted answer in 2017. I'm not so sure anymore, so I'm unaccepting my answer here to avoid misleading anyone. I'm not fiddling with Heroku + Docker these days, so I'm not in a good position to accept an answer.

TL;DR Ensure that `bash` is installed in the image and add this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

**Explanation**

Contrary to what [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#enabling-docker-support) would lead one to believe, Heroku does not, out of the box, support `heroku ps:exec` into a Docker container already running in a dyno.

Quoting from responses I have received from the Heroku team:

> Our ps:exec feature ... works ... by injecting a bash file into dynos,
> opening an additional port in the background, and allowing you to
> connect to it.
>
> [T]he default
> shell used by Docker is /bin/sh, which is not compatible with the
> Heroku Exec script (it's requires /bin/bash).
>
> There is a workaround you can use though. Put the following in your
> Dockerfile:
>
> `RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh`
>
> This is definitely a gap in
> our product, and we'll work to make this better.

Comment: I'd be surprised if simply replacing `sh` with a symlink to `bash` works. If invoked as `sh`,`bash` enters a posix compliant mode (https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bash/bash.1.en.html) which does not support `process substitution`(https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). `heroku-exec.sh` uses process substitution (`...  <(curl ... )`). 

Try `$ rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh`, 
`$ /bin/bash -c "cat <(echo 1)"`
`$ /bin/sh -c "cat <(echo 1)"`

Comment: Adding `set +o posix` in the heroku-exec script could help.

Comment: @wwerner can you give extra detail about how to add ```set +o posix``` to ```heroku-exec.sh```? I'm struggling with this problem right now. If you can give some extra advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175807/heroku-heroku-psexec-not-working-when-deploying-a-container-into-a-dyno will be awesome!

Comment: i've tried my own docker image heroku/heroku:16 image, ps:exec is still not working, i started the container with "heroku ps:scale web=1", or should i start with another command?

Comment: hm finally, got it working, on container image 'heroku/heroku:16' from docker hub only

Comment: I tried this command with a debian buster image and got the error message `rm: cannot remove '/bin/sh': Permission denied`

Comment: This answers a question that is different from the one that is asked. OP is not trying to run commands in the shell during the build, they are trying to get console access after it has been deployed.

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau It does answer the question "how can one open a shell into the already-running container?" The answer: Do what this answer says and then you can `heroku ps:exec` (As of 2017 this was the answer. No idea if it's still the best way.)

Comment: @kkurian oh, I see. Indeed it does (did). Thanks for clarifying...

Answer (score 8):

If bash is installed, run [`heroku run bash`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#testing-an-image-locally). This will get you into the shell from your command line.

You can also use the GUI and go to "More" -> "Run Console" on your heroku app, and input "bash" to bring it up there.

Comment: Trying this in the web console as you mentioned, is ultimately what worked for me. The `cli` took too long to respond, so not sure if it would have worked had I waited longer.

Comment: no, 'heroku run bash' is one-off, it's a separate new container of the same image, u don't see the existing processes running

Answer (score 5):

**Edited**:
In order to run heroku ps:exec on apps with Docker and deployed via the Container Registry you have to enable `runtime-heroku-exec`.
You can do `heroku features:enable runtime-heroku-exec` to enable it

[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#enabling-docker-support) you can see the documentation of `exec` with the instructions to enable docker support

Comment: I have tried all of that. No dice. See the example I've added to the question. Do you get different results from the example? Is the example missing something?

Comment: As of now, the documentation is misleading. See my answer.

Comment: this is just enabling the feature, i use the image heroku/heroku:16 and it's already there, the stuggle is 'heroku ps:exec' won't run :(

Comment: hm finally, got it working, on container image 'heroku/heroku:16' from docker hub only

Answer (score 2):

in my situation, to get this working with Ubuntu 20.04 (focal), i had to additionally install the `python-is-python3` package into the docker image, to get heroku-exec working.

---

here is a working example (october 2020) of an ubuntu-based dockerfile, that works with heroku-exec:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

# install required packages
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 curl python-is-python3 openssh-server iproute2 nginx && apt-get clean

# simplfy nginx config to enable ENV variable substitution
RUN echo 'server { listen PORT_NUMBER; }' > /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# add config required for HEROKU_EXEC
# ENV HEROKU_EXEC_DEBUG=1
RUN rm /bin/sh \
 && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh \
 && mkdir -p /app/.profile.d/ \
 && printf '#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\nset +o posix\n\n[ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ] && source <(curl --fail --retry 7 -sSL "$HEROKU_EXEC_URL")\n' > /app/.profile.d/heroku-exec.sh \
 && chmod +x /app/.profile.d/heroku-exec.sh

# configure NGINX to listen on dynamic $PORT env variable supplied by Heroku.
CMD sed -i 's/PORT_NUMBER/'"$PORT"'/g' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default; nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

then connect with this command:

```
heroku ps:exec -a name-of-app-12345
```

Comment: and how big is this image ? is it possible to run it on free account or is too big?

Comment: @PawelW in my case the the resulting image stored in the heroku docker registry was 241MB.  this works fine in a free account.   // also see this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#known-issues-and-limitations // "While Docker images are not subject to size restrictions (unlike slugs), they are subject to the dyno boot time restriction."

Answer (score 1):

Both `heroku run /bin/bash` and `heroku ps:exec` won't work in my situation. The former opens a new container which is different from the real one running! The latter just doesn't work in my container of alpine3, though `heroku features:enable runtime-heroku-exec` can succeed. My solution is to bring up a shell server and a traffic forwarder in the container. Then on the client connect to the shell server with tunnel created by traffic forwarder.

traffic flow:

```
localhost:2023 -> chisel client -> ...tunnel... -> chisel server -> localhost:8182
```

In conainer, start up a shell server with socat and a tunnel server with chisel:

```
nohup socat tcp-l:8182,reuseaddr,fork exec:/bin/bash,pty,setsid,setpgid,stderr,ctty > /tmp/socat.log 2>&1 &

nohup ./chisel server --port $PORT --proxy http://httpbin.org > /tmp/chisel.log 2>&1 &
```

On client side, start a chisel client to forward traffic from localhost:8182 to the socat on the server

```
chisel client http://yourapp.herokuapp.com/  0.0.0.0:2023:localhost:8182
```

on client side, open another terminal window:

```
socat -,raw,echo=0 tcp:127.0.0.1:2023
```

How to get the chisel on server? Download it or just compile from source in Dockerfile

download [chisel](https://github.com/jpillora/chisel/releases)

Answer (score 0):

One probably root cause is the docker not running in detached mode on Heroku.

https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/run-containers/#run-in-detached-mode

Have someone do know how to activate -d option when the container is being executed by Heroku?