# Heroku: "heroku ps:exec" not working when deploying a container into a dyno

Tags: bash, docker, heroku, openssh

I'm deploying a Tensorflow Serving container to Heroku, everything is working fine, but when I try to ssh into the container for executing some commands, Heroku returns this error:

```
C:\Users\whitm\Desktop\CodeProjects\deep-deblurring-serving>heroku ps:exec
Establishing credentials... error
 !    Could not connect to dyno!
 !    Check if the dyno is running with `heroku ps'
```

The Dyno is running correctly:

```
C:\Users\whitm\Desktop\CodeProjects\deep-deblurring-serving>heroku ps
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): /bin/sh -c bash\ heroku-exec.sh (1)
web.1: up 2020/04/11 19:13:51 -0400 (~ 38s ago)
```

I found a StackOverflow question from two years ago: [Shell into a Docker container running on a Heroku dyno. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652928/shell-into-a-docker-container-running-on-a-heroku-dyno-how). I already take care of all the details explained on the question, and the official Heroku docs about this specific situation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#using-with-docker, but I'm can't make this working.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving
LABEL maintainer="Whitman Bohorquez" description="Build tf serving based image. This repo must be used as build context"

COPY / /

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y git \
&& git reset --hard \
&& apt-get install -y curl \
&& apt-get install -y openssh-server

ENV MODEL_NAME=deblurrer

# Updates listening ports
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash \n\n\
tensorflow_model_server \
--rest_api_port=$PORT \
--model_name=${MODEL_NAME} \
--model_base_path=/models/${MODEL_NAME} \
"$@"' > /usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh \
&& chmod +x /usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh

# Setup symbolic link from sh to bash
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

CMD bash heroku-exec.sh
```

Special care in the line `RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh`. Im installing Curl, OpenSSH, Python already in the container. I create the file `heroku-exec.sh` with `[ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ] && source <(curl --fail --retry 3 -sSL "$HEROKU_EXEC_URL")` inside it, and successfully copy it into the `/app/.profile.d` folder, that is, the final route of the file is `/app/.profile.d/heroku-exec.sh`. Inclusive I tried do the last step as if the container is in a Heroku Private Space (that is not the case) but I will remove that.

Don't know what else to try, hope some help, I feel I'm doing something wrong with the `heroku-exec.sh` file, but what you think?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this?

Comment: I was not able to find a solution, I just decide to stop trying ssh into the container deployed on Heroku, sorry, this is a mess. Looks like the Dynos, that I guess are containers themselves, have problems communicating to our containers, so that is why they don't have natural support for this feature and everything must be setup with the guidelines on the docs, anyways that guidelines dont work for me. Im missing something, but dont know what. I you are not deploying tensorflow serving, but other type of app, like a flask api, just go the native Heroku way, keep docker for local testing.

Comment: @ElPapi42 found a solution yet? without ssh, it's just damn slow building image again and again

Comment: hm finally, got it working, on container image 'heroku/heroku:16' from docker hub only

Comment: That solution is good for many use cases, in my case, I'm starting my image from the Tensorflow Serving image, and that is crucial for my use case, so i cant just swap it with heroku:16 stack, maybe i can do something with multistage builds, but i will stop for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue and this solution worked for me.

**Note:** Make sure you are creating container from an image that has all binaries that Heroku requires.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 heroku/heroku:20
```

1. Add buildpack using [this script](https://github.com/heroku/exec-buildpack/blob/master/opt/heroku-exec.sh)
2. Enable the heroku-exec feature on app:

   `heroku features:enable runtime-heroku-exec`
3. Add a `.profile.d` directory in our DockerFile and have it copied over (use COPY command) to `/app/.profile.d`. Use the `heroku-exec.sh` from [buildpack version](https://github.com/heroku/exec-buildpack/blob/master/opt/heroku-exec.sh) and make sure it's present in the `.profile.d` before copy.
4. Add execution permission on `heroku-exec.sh` after copy.
5. Add this run command to Dockerfile after the copy -

   `RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh`
6. Finally use `heroku ps:exec -a <appName> --dyno=<dynoName>` to login.