# Heroku can not ssh into a free dyno

Tags: heroku

What I am trying to do:

[image]

What I have done to resolve the issue:

**1.** [image]

**2.** From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542020/visualvm-on-heroku-with-docker): yes, I have `/app/.profile.d/heroku-exec.sh`.

**3.** [image]

**4.** I found also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652928/shell-into-a-docker-container-running-on-a-heroku-dyno-how). And saw that `rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh` may help. But it is for docker and I do not know where to insert it if I do not use docker. I tried to create `Procfile` with the following content: `web: rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh` (do not judge me, I just tried). But in this case a dyno only crashed.

I was a little confused when I did not find relevant information about this error. Heroku does not provide docs for this error. As a variant I guess that `Establishing credentials... error` could mean that I do not pass any authentication. May be. But which one? I can `heroku run bash` which means that I pass the authentication. Maybe `exec` requires ssh keys?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to try `heroku ps:exec --ssh --dyno=web.1`. By default the `ps:exec` command uses internal SSH support, but if you specify the `--ssh` flag it'll use your native SSH client which might help.

Comment: Finally: if you had previously owned your app and ssh'd into a dyno, then destroyed/re-created the app, you might have issues.

Comment: @rdegges Just created a new app and with it `exec` works. Do not understand.

Comment: It's because you had already created an app with the same name previously and tried to SSH into it. Each time you SSH to a host your computer remembers the host's fingerprint. If a host changes (eg: you destroy/re-create an app of the same name) the fingerprint will now be different which means you won't be able to access it without first deleting the origin host's fingerpring from your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. It's sort of a long explanation :(